# Using ggplot to map multiple polygons from a .txt file

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a database of hundreds of polygons (operational areas of fisheries) that I pulled into R (as .shps) and converted to dataframes, then saved them in a .txt file with 8 columns:
"long"  "lat"   "order" "hole"  "piece" "id"    "group" "name" 
where "name" is the text string name I gave each polygon, and the column I want to use as the id for which coordinates belong to which polygon. I use read.table to  read in the data frame (called "mypolygons"), and then my problem comes when I try to use ggplot to plot the polygons in several different ways - the most basic just being plotting the areas on a lat/long grid.

```
ewbrks <- seq(-180,180,45)
nsbrks <- seq(-90,90,30)
ggplot(mypolygons, aes(x=long,y=lat, group=mypolygons$name))+ 
geom_polygon(aes())+
geom_path(colour="black") + 
scale_x_continuous(breaks = ewbrks, expand = c(0,0)) +
scale_y_continuous(breaks = nsbrks, expand = c(0,0)) +
theme_bw()
```

I've tried it with a mini version of the database, with only 2 polygons. The result I'm getting is a very strange map with the polygons in the wrong place, since one is supposed to be in the Bering Sea and the other off of Mexico.

I'm new to ggplot (and using R for mapping) and I can't figure out if it's a problem with the way I'm made the .txt file, or with my ggplot code. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The problem might be that that you are using group=mypolygons$name rather than group=name. Otherwise you will have to provide a reproducible example. Use dput() on (a portion of) mypolygons

Comment: Thanks @RichardTelford, that was part of the problem. Still having issues with how I set up the .txt file, but that's a different problem